# Problem with upgrading from Laravel 6 to Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel-6, laravel-7, laravel-upgrade

I was trying to upgrade my Laravel Project from 6 to 7 and I have already upgraded other dependencies that Laravel version 7 requires.
I tried to run `php require laravel/framework "^7.0"` but it's showing me the following error.

```
 Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v7.0.0, v6.0.0].
    - don't install laravel/framework v7.0.0|don't install illuminate/support v6.0.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.0.0].
    - Installation request for illuminate/support 6.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v6.0.0], laravel/framework[v6.0.0].
```

---

I have just run `composer update` then changed `laravel/framework to "^7.0"`. This is my current `composer.json`,

```
{
    "name": "laravel-project",
    "description": "laravel-project",
    "type": "project",
    "keywords": [
        "php",
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://test.in/",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Ujjwal Wahi",
            "email": "opuslabsin@gmail.com",
            "homepage": "http://opuslabs.in/"
        }
    ],
    "support": {
        "email": "test@gmail.com"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "laravel-dotenv-editor",
            "options": {
                "symlink": true
            }
        },
        {
            "url": "https://github.com/ujjwalwahi/laravel-wallet.git",
            "type": "git"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://github.com/ujjwalwahi/plans.git",
            "type": "git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.0",
        "albertcht/invisible-recaptcha": "^1.9",
        "arcanedev/log-viewer": "~5.0",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "~3.0",
        "berkayk/onesignal-laravel": "^1.0",
        "brotzka/laravel-dotenv-editor": "^2.0",
        "brozot/laravel-fcm": "1.3.*",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "creativeorange/gravatar": "~1.0",
        "doctrine/inflector": "1.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "illuminate/support": "6.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "kyslik/column-sortable": "^6.0",
        "labs64/netlicensingclient-php": "^2.3",
        "laravel/helpers": "^1.1",
        "laravel/passport": "^8.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "2.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^6.0",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "~4.0",
        "rachidlaasri/laravel-installer": "^4.0",
        "yabacon/paystack-php": "^2.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.2",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "prefer-stable": true }
```

but I am getting the following error now.

```
 Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove brozot/laravel-fcm 1.3.1
    - Conclusion: don't install brozot/laravel-fcm 1.3.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.25.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.24.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.23.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.23.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.23.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.22.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.22.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.22.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.22.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.22.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.21.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.20.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.19.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.19.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.18.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.17.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.17.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.16.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.16.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.15.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.14.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.14.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.13.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.12.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.11.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.10.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.10.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.10.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.10.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.9.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.9.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.8.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.8.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.7.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.7.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.6.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.6.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.6.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.5.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.5.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.4.0
    - Installation request for brozot/laravel-fcm 1.3.* -> satisfiable by brozot/laravel-fcm[1.3.0, 1.3.1
].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.1
    - brozot/laravel-fcm 1.3.0 requires illuminate/support 5.*|^6 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.
0.0], illuminate/support[v6.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v7.0.0, v6.0.0].
    - don't install laravel/framework v7.0.0|don't install illuminate/support v6.0.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.0.0, v7.0.1,
 v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1
, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.1
7.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.21.0, v7.22.0, v7.22.1, v7.2
2.2, v7.22.3, v7.22.4, v7.23.0, v7.23.1, v7.23.2, v7.24.0, v7.25.0, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.

2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
```

Comment: Show your `composer.json` file

Comment: Don't update like this, first edit the `composer.json` then  run `composer update` here is the official doc https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade

Comment: my `composer.json` is as below.

Answer (score 0):

i used this package instead of brozot

```
composer require apility/laravel-fcm
```